# How to repair a severely damaged ext4 partition?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, fsck, corruption

I have a SDCard that has a ext4 partition that was badly damaged, if I try to mount, it outputs:

```
mount: mount /dev/mmcblk0p8 on /media failed: Stale file handle
```

This the superblock information:

```
tune2fs 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
Filesystem volume name:   root
Last mounted on:          <not available>
Filesystem UUID:          7014450b-327d-4a3e-a78a-d072ef01a6fe
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         unsigned_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         not clean with errors
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              522240
Block count:              2085632
Reserved block count:     104281
Free blocks:              2015490
Free inodes:              522229
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      509
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8160
Inode blocks per group:   510
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Wed Dec 31 21:02:02 1969
Last mount time:          n/a
Last write time:          Thu May 18 15:07:55 2017
Mount count:              0
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Wed Dec 31 21:02:02 1969
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          260 MB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      11e9ced2-8cb0-436b-aaca-16a2cfb7cb32
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

More information:

```
file -s /dev/mmcblk0p8
/dev/mmcblk0p8: Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem data (mounted or unclean), UUID=7014450b-327d-4a3e-a78a-d072ef01a6fe, volume name "root" (errors) (extents) (large files)
```

The command fsck fails time after time with:

```
e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
root contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Resize inode not valid.  Recreate<y>? yes
```

Can I try something more to recover the partition, I know that I can run photorec, but I wonder if I still fix the partition...

**UPDATE**

dmesg output has a lot of messages like this one:

```
[dom may 14 17:18:28 2017] mmcblk0: error -110 sending stop command, original cmd response 0x900, card status 0x900
```

Comment: I recommend contacting the ext4 mailing list: send an email to linux-ext4@vger.kernel.org with as much information as possible. I suspect they’d like to get the chance to improve `e2fsck` so it can cope with whatever issue is tripping it up here...

Comment: In addition to Stephen Kitt's suggestion, please make a full image copy of the partition. By making a copy and (ideally) making a second copy for each recovery attempt, you get unlimited retries, no matter how badly each recovery attempt goes. Plus SD cards are typically rather small, so it's easy to store a full image (or two, or three) on your HDD.

Comment: BTW: Have you checked `dmesg`? Need to make sure we're not dealing with, e.g., an SD card that has gone hard read-only due to flash wearing out.

Comment: @derobert I've appended such a data

Comment: @sebelk I'd suggest trying fsck on a copy of a copy... I suspect it might just be dieing from a write error.

Comment: This [link](https://nnc3.com/mags/Networking2/nfs/ch18_08.htm) may help. The first para says _A filehandle becomes stale whenever the file or directory referenced by the handle is removed by another host, while your client still holds an active reference to the object. A typical example occurs when the current directory of a process, running on your client, is removed on the server (either by a process running on the server or on another client)._